# why won't terminal recognize /ect directory directly?

Tags: command-line, directory

so, when i type in "ls /" it shows all the directories (including ect), but somehow I cannot make it change to the working directory...it works when I try switching it to the dev or bin directory, but i can't access the ect directory nor the password information inside it (i didn't lose the password info or anything im just messing around with the system)

thanks

Comment: Its `/etc`, not `/ect`

Comment: This is why `etc` vs `ect` matters. It's `/etc` not `ect` @heemayl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the directory name. It is `/etc`, not `/ect`.

Just to be clear, it seems you have not created a directory named `/ect` yourself so we can assume the standard name which is `/etc`.

I would suggest you to have a look at [`man hier`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/hier.7.html) to get more idea about how directories are laid out typically in Linux.

Comment: hahahaha, thanks! i make lots of mistakes of this nature....